# Book of sci-fi short stories: purple and black cover with sorceress and cat

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember owning a book that had a several short sci-fi stories. One was about an older couple who used to listen to the music in the rain. Another about a woman who wished for a hundred of everything. I think there was a story about bad kids who were sent to camp and then were eaten by dinosaurs? The cover was purple and black and had a sorceress and a cat on the cover(I think one of the stories was about her). I read it in the early nineties. Written in english and probably at a middle school level. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details? Every little bit helps us.

Comment: Thanks. I will do that. Especially if I can think of any more details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

[*Visions of Fantasy: Tales from the Masters*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?179085), a 1989 anthology edited by [Isaac Asimov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Asimov) and [Martin H. Greenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_H._Greenberg).

**One was about an older couple who used to listen to the music in the rain.**

I'm not sure about this one, but if it's one of the stories in that anthology, by elimination it's likely to be ["Voices in the Wind"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?60355) by Elizabeth S. Helfman.

**Another about a woman who wished for a hundred of everything.**

Not a hundred, but ["A Dozen of Everything"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?523837), by [Marion Zimmer Bradley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marion_Zimmer_Bradley), originally published in [*Fantastic*, April 1959](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?226045+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/FantasticV08N04195904#page/n67/mode/2up).

> "I'm afraid I don't quite understand." The djinn frowned. "Trousseau? That word has come in since my time. Remember, I haven't been out of the bottle since King Solomon was in diapers."
>
> "Well—sheets, and towels, and slips, and nightgowns—" Marcie began, then dismissed it. "Oh well, just give me a dozen of everything," she told him.
>
> "To hear is to obey," the djinn intoned. "Where shall I put it, O mistress?"
>
> "Oh, in my room," Marcie told him, then, remembering five-dollar-a-week hall bedroom, "Maybe you'll have to enlarge the room a little, but you can do that, can't you?"
>
> "Oh, sure," said the djinn casually. "A djinn, my dear mistress, can do anything. And now, farewell forever, and thank you for letting me out."

**I think there was a story about bad kids who were sent to camp and then were eaten by dinosaurs?**

That's ["Letters from Camp"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?93675) by [Al Sarrantonio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al_Sarrantonio):

> Mom and Dad, I think I'm the only kid left, and I don't know if I can hide much longer. The head counselor tricked us into leaving the camp today, saying that somebody had seen a Tyrannosaurus Rex. He told us all to run through the rain forest at the north end of the camp, but when we ran into it, something horrible happened.

Comment: Oh my goodness!  That's it!  Thank you so much!  Now I can buy a copy of it